# ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP but there is 500GB available

Tags: oracle

I keep getting this error "ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP" but the DBA tells me there's over 500GB available.

While what I'm trying to run will return a few million rows, I have queries that create 100M rows run successfully.

what can be the cause of this one failing if there's so much free space available?
The DBA doesn't seem to know what to do.

Upd. This was solved in comments, turned out my schema only had 60GB. Seems to work now. But I'm now confused, why isn't 60GB enough to run a query that will produce a few million rows.
All tables in my schema add up to 1GB.

Also, when they say that I have 60GB available, is that at the time of the run?

Comment: Possibly the DBA is looking at the CDB rather than the PDB (vice versa), i.e. you are both seeing different TEMP tablespaces.

Comment: Maybe the TEMP tablespace is not set to auto-extend and has reached its maximum size.

Comment: But there's 500GB available, doesn't that mean there's space?

Comment: @teng I gave him the message, he replied with "
Ppppp schema is in pdb having xxxxx_temp as temporary tablespace

Comment: Let's start with getting him to run `select * from dba_free_space where tablespace = 'TEMP' on both the CDB and PDB.

Comment: Then, post the result of `select file_name, AUTOEXTENSIBLE, BYTES, MAXBYTES, INCREMENT_BY  from dba_data_files where tablespace_name='TEMP'` on both CDB and PDB, then also do a `df -h` on the file systems (or equivalent on ASM if using that).

Comment: The TS having 500GB available when you check it (after the failed process) does not mean it had 500GB at the point the process failed.  When processes terminate (fail or normal) they release the space they were using.  And the fact that you have queries that successfully return more rows doesn't mean anything.  Perhaps your failing query is working with more rows than are finally returned, doing more sorting and/or joining.

Comment: @tengG your comment solved it :) somehow, it turned out that it was another schema that had 500, mine only had 60. So he added my schema to that one, I will now rerun and see what happens. But yes, I have the same question. When it says 60 go available, is that at the time of the run?

Comment: And another question is, why isn't 60gb enough to run a table with a few million rows

Comment: Number of rows is pretty meaningless. I could have a million rows of two integers take up less space than a single row that contains a single CLOB. The average width of your rows is as important as the number of rows.

Comment: Got it :) though this table has none of it. But let's say the final results table that's created from this query only takes 100MB. Why would it error with 60GB free? I mean, in theory it's possible that this query needs 60GB to run and then creates a table that's 100MB but i find it hard to believe.

Comment: @EdStevens I somehow missed your comment. Does this fact that he was checking for space as I was running the query change your answer? I understand everything you said, good points. How can I tell how much space a query is using to run?

Comment: There's one other point to keep in mind. Suppose you have a 500gb temp, and some process is using 490gb.  All is well. Then another process comes in and needs only 11gb, but at this point only 10 available The 11gb process will fail, but it was simply because he was last in line , not because he needed a massive amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error can also be a sign of a query needing optimization and sucking up space while running inefficiently.  We use the optimizer from Quest (Toad) and check for indexes, analyze the explain plan for problem areas to rework, etc.  Look for full table scans that can be eliminated with indexes, Cartesian products, etc.